# Android: TextView - Multiline EditText with Disabled Soft Keypad?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

In an app that I am writing I use the "singleLine" property of an EditText (inherited from TextView) in order to make the view multiline by setting the property to false:

```
mCalculatorInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
mCalculatorInput.setSingleLine(false);
```

The reason for this is the line above it, where I disable all use of the soft keypad in order to use my own keypad (calculator).  The question is whether or not the "singleLine" property is appropriate to use, and if not, what is the intended way of using InputType to simulate this type of behavior?

The strange thing btw is that I cannot seem to find any evidence of this being deprecated on the [Android developer site :](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3asingleLine)

But a quick google search shows quite a few people referring to this as deprecated, even from as far back as 2009 by someone from [CommonsWare:](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/bcf57d60afc1b666/7339988538200123?lnk=gst&q=Mark+Murphy)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [doc that shows it as deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine)

Did you try `setMaxLines(1)`?

Comment: Thanks, that most surely shows that it is deprecated.  However I suppose the main part of the question still remains: what to do in this situation?  Any combo of setMinLines and setMaxLines was not effective. Applying multiple InputTypes with "|" was also not effective.